# Disk space not available issue: Worklight 6.1.0.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

[image] I have installed worklight 6.1.0.1 plugin from market place in the Eclipse kepler.

I have following Issues with it:

1) After clean building the application for two times my 8 GB memory got occupied. I am restarting my system everytime to get back this memory. This is seriously annoying issue. Is there any fix for this?

2) I have shell component in my project. If I just build shell components and application my changes are not being reflected. I have to clean build the application every time if I want to see my changes. If I do so, I am landing up in memory not available issue. It is also taking 20 minutes+ for the whole process of cleaning, building shell and application.

I assuming that this is a common issue, hoping an positive reply for this.

Comment: Eclipse uses whichever amount of memory you allocate for it. Are you in fact getting a Java Heap Space error?

Comment: This is the error that I am getting:                                       "[WARNING ] ScriptWriter synch error: 
There is not enough space on the disk". And also this error "Failed to unzip files. There is not enough space on the disk"

Comment: @Idan: Please find the image attached above.

Comment: Your error is not about your MEMORY, but about your DISK space. Can you confirm you have enough disk space in the location the extraction takes places? your temp folder or some other folder in your HD. verify that.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I have edited the heading. Initially there was 10 gb. After cleaning the application for three times the memory got over. I would like to know if there is any proper solution for this. Occupying 10 GB after three builds sounds weird. and also its taking 20 minutes to clean build application and shell components.

Comment: To be honest, your numbers are weird... i have never seen a worklight project that takes 10GB of DISK SPACE. Can you elaborate on that? This is not common at all.

Comment: Okie. I have worklight project having a shell component. If i make a change in HTML file or Js file in the shell I need to build shell and application to see the changes reflected. But it is not reflecting if I just build shell and application. I have to clean the whole application and build both application and shell to see the changes that I made to reflect in the HTML and JS. If I do so its workspace size is increasing every time. Roughly From morning I have done three times. It expanded to 10 GB. First time I restarted my then the occupied disk space got got cleared and I got back my 10 GB

Comment: You do understand 10GB is a huge number, yes? What is the actual size of your app? What kind of resources do you have in it? I would try again with a fresh eclipse and a new workspace and a new app.

Comment: But second time when I restarted my PC, The temp files are as it is. Even after deleting my workspace, I got only 1.5 GB free space. I was using worklight 5.5 previously, I did not face these kind of problems at all.

Comment: It will be 35 mb. It is a e-commerce kind of application. I have dojo files and 15 images which will hardly be 2mb.

Comment: And if you try in a fresh eclipse with a new workspace and import the project into it?

Comment: I will try it and come back to you. Thanks for quick response :)

Comment: @Idan: I dont have even space to try cleaning the app. My system will crash. My C drive is running out of memory. I tried copying the eclipse and creating workspace in another drive but its targeting c only. I found that in AppData>Local>Temp, there are lot of folders like "shellResources352050850643394". They were having android and Iphone files in it. The total size of all the files is 12 GB. I deleted them. I think this is a temporary fix. But let me know if you get some permanent fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to APAR #PI32772, where when building a Shell component, the temp folder gets filled and filled and filled - but never gets cleaned, thus the disk runs out of available space.

To receive a fix for this issue a PMR support ticket must be opened.

The only available workaround is tot manually clean the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp directory\shellResourcesXXX folder.